# in kafka, what's the difference between group coordinator and the controller?

Tags: apache-kafka

I see in the doc

**controller**: we elect one of the brokers as the "controller". This controller detects failures at the broker level and is responsible for changing the leader of all affected partitions in a failed broker.
In a Kafka cluster, one of the brokers serves as the controller, which is responsible for managing the states of partitions and replicas and for performing administrative tasks like reassigning partitions. At any given time there is only one controller broker in your cluster.

**group coordinator**: one of the Kafka broker gets elected as a Group Coordinator. When a consumer wants to join a group, it sends a request to the coordinator. The first consumer to participate in a group becomes a leader. All other consumers joining later becomes the members of the group.

which one will likely be elected as group coordinator? is it always the same broker as the controller? How can I find out the group coordinator?

Answer (score 4):

Group co-ordinator is for each consumer group. So essentially, you have only 1 controller per cluster, but multiple group-coordinator (1 for each consumer group)

So, no, group co-ordinator will not always be the same broker that is the controller.

To find which broker is the group-coordinator for a consumer group, you can run:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my-consumer-group --describe --state
```

The difference between Controller and Group-coordinator lies in their role. While controller's main job is to elect the leader for each partition of a topic and manage cluster metadata, detect failure of other brokers; the role of group-coordinator is to manage a consumer group and specially partition rebalance.

This is how it's decided which broker will be the group co-ordinator

> When a consumer instance starts up it sends a FindCoordinator request
> that includes its group.id to any broker in the cluster. The broker
> will create a hash of the group.id and modulo that against the number
> of partitions in the internal __consumer_offsets topic. That
> determines the partition that all metadata events for this group will
> be written to. The broker that hosts the leader replica for that
> partition will take on the role of group coordinator for the new
> consumer group.

Full details [here](https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/architecture/consumer-group-protocol/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20consumer,the%20group%20coordinator.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm more clear about the difference. 
But how is the coordinator decided for each group? is it round robin or by group name hash or something?

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect the logic behind selection of broker for group co-ordinator role